# How to redirect to new view after successful login in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, redirect, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to build an app that redirects to the homepage after successful login. I have two view controllers: `LoginViewController` and `DashboardViewController`. I have coded the login part and i have created a view for the dashboard, But am not sure how to redirect to the `DashboardViewController` after successful login. I would really appreciate some help.

Here is the code I have for the `LoginViewController.m` file:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize userName,password,loginbutton,indicator;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


- (IBAction) loginButton: (id) sender
{
    // TODO: spawn a login thread

    indicator.hidden = FALSE;
    [indicator startAnimating];
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",userName.text, password.text];

    NSString *hostStr = @"******";
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"Result = '%@'", serverOutput); // look for space between quotes
    serverOutput = [serverOutput stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];



    if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){


        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorized"
            delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];


        }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Username or Password Incorrect"
            delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];
        loginbutton.enabled = TRUE;

    }


    loginbutton.enabled = FALSE;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.userName resignFirstResponder];
    [self.password resignFirstResponder];

}
```

@end

Comment: In alertView's delegate method write code pushing `DashboardViewController`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First  add `#import "DashboardViewController.h"` file in your `loginViewContrller.m` file

and create object of `DashboardViewController` in

```
if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
{
       DashboardViewController *newView = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
       [self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];

        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorized"
            delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! :) I'm new to building apps and still trying to figure out things.

Comment: -My Dashboard works now. I added a button to it to redirect to another view: ProfileViewController, but am getting the following error every time: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ProfileViewController 0xf8560c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key class.'" Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

1) Set the `tag` to the `alert` as alertsuccess.tag = 1;

2) Use following code for displaying next `ViewController`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1 && buttonIndex == 0)
    {
         DashboardViewController *vcDashboard = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
         if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0)
         {
             [self presentViewController:vcDashboard animated:YES completion:nil];
         }
         else
         {
             [self presentModalViewController:vcDashboard animated:YES];
         }
         [vcDashboard release];
    }
}
```